# How can I re-organize cells containing partial text from different cell into one Colum?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| header 1 | header 1 | header 3 | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'borough': 'ab' | 'postal_code': 'm1' | 'street': 'bbb' | ... |
| 'street': 'aaa' | 'borough': 'mz' | 'postal_code': '76' | ... |
| 'borough': 'an' | 'street': 'sda' | 'postal_code': 'in' | -- |
| 'street':'tre' | 'postal_code': '76' | 'borough': 'bb' | ... |
| etc.... | ... | ... | ... |

Hi.

consider the above table.  how can I organize the cells like the bellow table?

| header 1 | header 2 | header 3 | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'borough': 'ab' | 'postal_code': 'm1' | 'street': 'bbb' | ... |
| 'borough': 'mz' | 'postal_code': '76' | 'street': 'aaa' | ... |
| 'borough': 'an' | postal_code': 'in' | 'street': 'sda' | ... |
| 'borough': 'bb' | 'postal_code': '76' | 'street':'tre' | ... |
| etc.... | ... | ... | ... |

I have a large Excel sheet containing many cells and I want to re-organize cells containing partial text from different cells into one Colum.

Comment: `=SORT(A2:C2,1,1,TRUE)` in D2 and drag/copy down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(x,A2:C5,y,TOCOL(x),WRAPCOLS(SORTBY(y,TEXTBEFORE(y,":")),ROWS(x)))
```

Comment: I really appreciate it. it solved the problem.